# Error when creating a pipeline to encode categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to use XGBoost on a dataset with categorical variables. I used a pipeline to one-hot encode the values but I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
# Select categorical columns
categorical_cols = ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'Pclass']

# Select numerical columns
numerical_cols = ['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']

# Preprocessing for numerical data
numerical_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant')

# Preprocessing for categorical data
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

# Bundle preprocessing for numerical and categorical data
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ])


def get_score(n_estimators, learning_rate):
    model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators = n_estimators, early_stopping_rounds = 5, learning_rate = learning_rate, enable_categorical=True)
    
    my_pipeline = Pipeline(steps= [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                                  ('model', model)])
    
    my_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, 
             model__early_stopping_rounds=5, 
             model__eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
             model__verbose=False)
    predictions = my_pipeline.predict(X_valid)
    score = mean_absolute_error(predictions, y_valid)
    return score

get_score(300, 0.05)
```

I tried playing around with the `enable_categorical` argument but the error still appeared.